# How to frame a Search Query parameter using Google Drive API if a fileId is Trashed =true?

Tags: google-drive-api

In Google Drive API, how can I frame a query parameter finding an File id say "0BDE899DDDDDGG" is trashed=true? Some example would help.

I know that we can use [file.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) and from Json response we can get `labels.trashed` attribute to find out if the file is in the trashed or not. But this way i need to look in the response,  i want to query the call to return with a file info with trashed =false in request. how can i frame this in the Request call using [search Query parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters)

```
function getDriveFile(accessToken, fileId, callback, errorCallback, completeCallback) {
    // Return if parameters for Google AJAX request are not valid
    if (!verifyAllArgumentsNotEmpty(accessToken, fileId)) {
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({
        timeout: 10000, // Timeout (in ms) = 10sec
        url: _getGoogleDriveUrl(fileId),
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
        },
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (typeof(callback) === 'function') {
                callback(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
            }
        },
        error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (typeof(errorCallback) === 'function') {
                errorCallback(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
            }
        },
        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            if (typeof(completeCallback) === 'function') {
                completeCallback(jqXHR, textStatus);
            }
        }
    });
}

function _getGoogleDriveUrl(fileId) {
    var host = "../"; // relative path to proxy
    var proxyName = contextUrl;
    var result = host+proxyName+'/drive/v2/files/';
    if ($.trim(fileId) !== '') {
        result = result + fileId;
                }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Why don't you want to look at the response object?

Comment: That because google is taking approximately 2 hours to update a folder status in the JSON response trashed =true.

Comment: So thought that if i made a request query in such a way that asking trashed=true or not then it might send me a accurate response.

Comment: so you're trashing a folder, and for 2 hours, if you GET that folder it is showing trashed=false? That sounds like a bug if it's repeatable. Have you tried from https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#try-it and confirmed the behaviour? If the folder has files in it, it might be worth explicitly trashing them and then trash the empty folder.

Comment: YES.When i trashed a file not deleted, IN JSON response i see that trashed =false. In the https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#try-it i see trashed =true instantaneously in the Response. i don't understand why their is a difference like that.i have posted my GET request. Why i see 2 different behavior?

Comment: it's either a bug in your app, or there is some delay caused by Drive deleting files in the folder. I suspect it's more likely to be your app

Comment: It's because of browser caching Ajax request.